# Custom Django user authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have this code

```
def permit(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.user.id == pk:
        return render_to_response(HttpRequest.path)
    else:
        return render_to_response('forbidden.html')
```

What I'd like to do is, if the user is authenticated (`request.user.id == pk`) then he is allowed to download a link which he had clicked on prior to the authentication test. By `Httprequest.path` I hope to get the exact path he requested.

When I run this code, however, I am always redirected to the forbidden html, which means that `request.user.id == pk` is always false, even though it should sometimes be true.

Comment: or should I use ForeignKey?

Comment: How are you calling this? What is the value of pk?